# How do I get to terminal after upgrading to 13.10

Tags: boot

I upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10 and now when system starts it goes to a black screen.

I believe that the problem is related to the drivers for the NVidia graphics cards.

How can I get to a terminal so as to disable the updated driver??

Thanks

Comment: posssible duplicated http://askubuntu.com/q/162075/169736

Answer (score -1):

Try Strg + Alt + F1 to open the console even if you're not logged in.

You might need to add a function key if you are on a laptop.